# ASP.NET login attemps log?

Tags: .net, asp.net

How can I get/build a log of login attemps in an ASP.NET site?

Is there a hook I can use in the Form Authentication configuration to get this automatically (as opposed to saving manually some record in a database?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [ASP.NET Health Monitoring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998306.aspx), you can subscribe to [WebAuthenticationSuccessAuditEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.management.webauthenticationsuccessauditevent.aspx) and WebAuthenticationFailureAuditEvent.

1. [How To: Use Health Monitoring in ASP.NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998306.aspx)
2. [FAQ - Health Monitoring in ASP.NET 2.0](http://blogs.msdn.com/erikreitan/archive/2006/05/22/603586.aspx)

If you need more help, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

In the websites I work on, this gets saved as part of the login code. If there is a "business logic layer" it goes there, else it goes in the data layer.